# BluetoothLE Проблема при подсоединении устройства c пин-кодом

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, android-bluetooth

После сканирования получаю соединение с найденным прибором. Все стандартно: читаются сервисы и характеристики, посылается ответ и прибор спарился. Так это все хорошо работало, пока не понадобилось присоединить прибор, который требует пин-код. Теперь после того, как отправляю ответ, вылазит окно, которое требует пин-код. И на android6 все работает. Но возникла проблема на телефоне с android7. Окно для пина не появляется, зато в логе появляется странная строка:

LocalBluetoothPreferences: Found no reason to show the dialog - do not show dialog.

Я понимаю, что это значит, что нету причин открывать диалог. Но мне-то надо, чтобы дилог открылся, иначе как ввести пин? Как это исправить?

После некоторых тестов стало ясно, что это происходит не на всех Android-7. Только один так себя ведет, на 2-х других, на которых я смогла проверить, все работает. Не работает на Nexus-6 c системой Android-7.